# jQuery скрыть блок родителя

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть такой код.
При запуске, он скрывает текст всех элементов кроме тех что с текстом Show, вопрос, нужно сделать так чтобы он скрывал не только текст, но и весь блок вместе с родителем иначе так остаются рамки красные без текста.

```js
                    $('div.name').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).text() !== 'Show') {
                            $(this).css('display', 'none');
                        }
                    });
```

```css
li {
border:1px solid red;
margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
<a href="#" class="ui-btn">
<div class="name">Show</div>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#" class="ui-btn">
<div class="name">Hide</div>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#" class="ui-btn">
<div class="name">Hide</div>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Заменить  `$(this).css('display', 'none');` на    `$(this).parnt().css('display', 'none');` Полный код `$('div.name').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() !== 'Show') {
             $(this).parnt().css('display', 'none');
        }
 });`

Comment: родитель в вашем понимании это `div`, `a` или `li`?

Comment: родитель это li

Comment: Тогда так  `$(this).closest('li').hide();`

Comment: Vanya Avchyan Первый вариант не сработал, а вот второй сработал.

Огромное вам спасибо  Vanya Avchyan ))

Comment: Вместо `!== 'Show'` лучше проверять `== 'Hide'`, чтоб была однозначность, что если hide, то hide))... Вообще в ответе я написал более простой вариант. Обрати на него внимание

Comment: Пожалуйста.Смотрите ответ Алексея Шиманского.Нормально парень объясняет.Ато  бы  я добавил свой ответ :)

Comment: Vanya Avchyan да ладно, пусть с циклом велосипедит)

Comment: Цикл тут нужен, тут код на 4600 строк, очевидно что я скинул только ту часть которую не понял как реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Цикл тут вообще не нужен. Достаточно использовать **[contains](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83)**, чтобы выбрать  элементы, которые содержат строку *Hide* и **[closest](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA)**, чтобы выбрать ближайшего подходящего предка.

```js
/*
// Этот код работает. Но он избыточен
$('div.name').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() !== 'Show') {
    $(this).closest('li').hide();    
  }
});
*/

$("div.name:contains('Hide')").closest('li').hide();
```

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn">
    <div class="name">Show</div>
  </a>
</li>

<li>
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn">
    <div class="name">Hide</div>
  </a>
</li>

<li>
  <a href="#" class="ui-btn">
    <div class="name">Hide</div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Я бы плюсанул только вот закончились плюсики на сегодня :).Так что так +

Comment: Я скинул вам часть кода, Цикл там нужен.

Comment: @S1lllver в ответе, так или иначе, он (вариант решения через цикл) присутствует........ Только это довольно странное поведение - скидывать не тот код, над которым производится работа. Всё равно что  спрашивать о том ка починить спицы на колесе, хотя на самом деле у тебя трактор беларусь..

Comment: вопрос был не про цикл, соответственно цикл тут не причем )

Comment: @S1lllver еще как причем. вопрос был `чтобы он скрывал не только текст, но и весь блок вместе с родителем`. Из твоего приложенного кода (если он не причем, то непонятно зачем он тогда был вообще представлен) можно сделать вывод, что ты бегаешь по всем элементам `div.name` и пытаешься работать с ними.... Что, конечно же, не является необходимым.....Более того, если внутри цикла есть какая-то логика, то, опять же, чтобы скрыть элементы с `Hide` этот цикл не нужен) Ну да пофиг.

Comment: Ну естетсвенно что ты не поймешь логику, я повторюсь там очень много кода, что я и сам логику не понимаю )
этот код писали 4 программиста, я 5ый, главное все работает и все.
Если бы писал код я, конечно же я написал бы хороший код и правильный код, но быдло код поддерживать нелегко

Comment: @S1lllver  вполне легко - просто не рефакторишь и всё :D .......обрати внимание на закомментированный код ответа :D